# What is a literal string & char array in C?

Tags: c

Firstly, I included C++ as C++ is just a parent of C, so I'm guessing both answers apply here, although the language I'm asking about and focusing on in this question is C, and not C++.

So I began reading the C book 'Head First C' not so long ago. In the book (page 43/278) it will answer a question for you. Are there any differences between
literal strings and character arrays.

I was totally thrown by this as I didn't know what a literal string was. I understand a string is just a array of characters, but what makes a 'string' literal? And why is it mentioning string in C if C doesn't actually provide any class (like a modern language such as C# or Java would) for string.

Can anyone help clean up this confusion? I really struggle to understand what Microsoft had to say about this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kc54dd5.aspx) and think I need a more simple explanation I can understand.

Comment: A string literal is one that appears in the actual source code. As opposed to one that is (for example) created behind the scenes by `sprintf` or some such thing. It's one where the actual representation is right there in the source code for all to see.

Comment: I think this has been referred to as a "hard coded string" in other languages? If I'm right then I understand it.

Comment: " as C++ is just a parent of C" - no, it isn't.

Comment: You can't say it isn't as you didn't ask what I meant by defining it as a "parent." (maybe a 'child' would be a better definition). From my limited knowledge, C++ is a rewrite of C with extended features. I apologize if I'm wrong but answers in both languages would be similar, or exact even.

Comment: "you didn't ask what I meant by defining it as a "parent."." -  if we had to do that, we would have to ask what you mean by every word in your question, which is obviously not possible. I've removed the C++ tag as you specifically say your question is about C.

Comment: I understand that. I'll put it down to bad naming and improve my writing in future questions, I apologize.

Comment: @partikao You're correct in saying that C++ is mostly a superset of C. It's just that here on SO people usually prefer when you ask about C *or* C++, because in some cases answers for C and C++ would differ drastically. (Not in this case, though.)

Comment: C++ *was* almost completely a superset but since C99 there has been *more* divergence, not less.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat There is sufficient difference between C and C++ that make a proper answer to OP's question different especially the language's use of _literal_.

Comment: @partikao Note that the first C++ compilers started off as C++ source --> C source --> code "compliers".  So initially, anything C++ could do (albeit more convoluted), C could do making C++ a subset.  Much has evolved since then including a general separation of the languages.

Comment: @chux I wasn't aware of that difference before seeing your answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A string literal is an unnamed string constant in the source code. E.g. `"abc"` is a string literal.

If you do something like `char str[] = "abc";`, then you could say that `str` is *initialized with a literal*. `str` itself is not a literal, since it's not *unnamed*.

A string (or C-string, rather) is a contiguous sequence of bytes, terminated with a null byte.

A char array is not necessarily a C-string, since it might lack a terminating null byte.

Comment: I think I understand. A literal string is simple just something like `function_name("literal string")`. Although one thing, would something like `auto literalString = "literal string"` still be a literal string, as it doesn't really fall under "constant" as the variable itself `literalString` can be changed.

Comment: @partikao `auto literalString = "literal string"` is not a literal because it has a name. Literals don't.

Comment: To clarify `"literal string"` is a literal, `literalString` is not - it's a pointer to a const char.

Answer (score 4):

> What is a literal string & char array in C?

C has 2 kinds of *literals*:  *string literals* and *compound literals*.  Both are unnamed and both can have their address taken.  *string literals* can have more than 1 *null character* in them.

In the C library, a *string* is characters up to and including the first *null character*. So a *string* always has one and only one *null character*, else it is not a *string*. A *string* may be `char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`.

```
//          v---v string literal 6 char long
char *s1 = "hello";
char *s2 = "hello\0world";
//          ^----------^  string literal 12 char long

char **s3 = &"hello";  // valid

//        v------------v  compound literal
int *p1 = (int []){2, 4};
int **p2 = &(int []){2, 4};  // vlaid
```

C specifies the following as constants, not literals, like  `123`, `'x'` and `456.7`.  These *constants* can not have their address taken.

```
int *p3 = &7; // not valid
```

C++ and C differ in many of these regards.

---

A `char`array is an *array* of `char`.  An array may consist of many *null characters*.

```
char a1[3];          // `a1` is a char array size 3
char a2[3] = "123";  // `a2` is a char array size 3 with 0 null characters 
char a3[4] = "456";  // `a3` is a char array size 4
char a4[] = "789";   // `a4` is a char array size 4
char a5[4] = { 0 };  // `a5` is a char array size 4, all null characters
```

The following `t*` are *not* `char` arrays, but pointers to `char`.

```
char *t1;
char *t2 = "123";
int *t3 = (char){'x'};
```

Comment: Touche, I didn't know about this difference in naming between C and C++.