# Does multiple pointer allocation may cause an overflow?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

I'm trying to understand memory management with C. So far I have a clear overview, but there's a question that is not that obvious for me.

If I declare a `char` pointer and assign it some string, then the pointer contains the address to that string (that is allocated somwhere).

```
char *pchar1 = "Hello World OLD";
unsigned long x = (unsigned long)pchar1; //Note that I'm storing the value of this addr for further usage
printf("pchar1 content: %s\n", pchar1); // Hello World OLD
printf("Adress of pchar1: %lu\n\n", pchar1); //<Some Random Addr>
```

If I assign another string to the pointer, then it aims to another address.

```
pchar1 = "Hello World NEW";
printf("pchar1 content: %s\n", pchar1); // Hello World NEW
printf("Adress of pchar1: %lu\n\n", pchar1); // <A different addrs than the fisrt one>
```

If I try to read the old memory location I found that there's still my old string

```
printf("Old addr stores in 'x': %lu\n", x); // Hello World OLD
printf("Reading old pchar1 mem addr (from x): %s\n\n", (char *)x); // <The First Address>
```

My question is, as memory used **is not being freed** and If I don't store the value for old memory addr then **I lost track of it**, may something like this cause an overflow?

```
while(1){
        pchar1 = "Hello World OLD"; //Stores this string in a different addres
        pchar1 = "Hello World NEW"; //Stores this string in a different addres
    }
```

The following this the whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char *pchar1 = "Hello World OLD";
    unsigned long x = (unsigned long)pchar1;

    

    printf("pchar1 content: %s\n", pchar1);
    printf("Adress of pchar1: %lu\n\n", pchar1);
   
    pchar1 = "Hello World NEW";
    printf("pchar1 content: %s\n", pchar1);
    printf("Adress of pchar1: %lu\n\n", pchar1);

    printf("Old addr stores in 'x': %lu\n", x);
    printf("Reading old pchar1 mem addr (from x): %s\n\n", (char *)x);

    //Overflow?
    while(1){
        pchar1 = "Hello World OLD"; //Stores this string in a different addres
        pchar1 = "Hello World NEW"; //Stores this string in a different addres
    }

    printf("\nSuccess!...\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: no overflow, these are both [string _literals_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50125126/what-is-a-literal-string-char-array-in-c) and probably stored in a read-only portion of memory. All you're doing with `pchar1 = ` is assigning the address of the string literal to `pchar1`. Both strings will exist for the duration of your program at their own addresses.

Comment: Also, see [how to print a pointer in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197757/printing-pointers-in-c)

Comment: Got it, but as Im storing string literals in an infinite while loop, every asssignment takes a space in read only mem as you said, does it have a limit?

Comment: nope, `pchar` is a pointer that has enough space to store a pointer. Each assignment in your loop overwrites the previous assignment, they don't accumulate on into infinity somehow. Once the 2nd assignment is made the previous one is lost ,, then rinse and repeat each iteration.

Comment: If you actually needed to convert pointers to integers, you would want to use `uintptr_t` (or `intptr_t`) rather than `unsigned long`. But you very probably *don't* need to convert pointers to integers. Just store them as pointers, and if you want to print their values, cast to `void*` and use `"%p"`.

Comment: This is essentially a form of "static leak" but it is harmless apart from the wasted memory. Unlike dynamic memory leaks which contribute to heap fragmentation etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String constants are typically stored in a static read-only section of your program's memory.  Such constants are available for the full lifetime of the program, whether you keep a pointer to them or not.

Also, if a string constant appears more than once in a program, it's not uncommon for each of those instances to refer to the same piece of memory.

In this particular case:

```
while(1){
    pchar1 = "Hello World OLD"; //Stores this string in a different addres
    pchar1 = "Hello World NEW"; //Stores this string in a different addres
}
```

You have two string constants stored in that read-only memory segment.  On each iteration of the loop `pchar1` is modified to point to one of those string constants.  So it's not creating more memory that's being used.

If on the other hand you have something like this:

```
void foo(void)
{
    char s[] = "Some very very very long string";
    foo();
}
```

And you call `foo`, there will be an array on the stack which stores the string `"Some very very very long string"` once for each iteration of the function, and eventually you will run out of stack space, and the larger `s` is the quicker that will happen.

Comment: First of all thanks for your response. Let's suppose that I generate a random string within the infinite loop, in that case does the read only mem would fill?

Comment: @EdherCarbajal That depends on exactly what "generate a random string" means.

Comment: Let's say that I generate very very long random strings in each iteration, as you said in your response " Such constants are available for the full lifetime of the program, whether you keep a pointer to them or not." Then, Would I reach a point where there's no more memory left for storing that?

Comment: @EdherCarbajal If you're creating strings at run time, they're not constant.

Comment: So in that case that I'm creating those string in runtime, wouldn't it fill the mem? I'm sorry I just try to get it clear

Comment: @EdherCarbajal If you're building an array declared outside of the loop, then you're overwriting the contents of that array on each iteration.  If you declare an array inside the loop and use that, the array's lifetime ends after a loop iteration and a new array's lifetime begins on the next.

Answer (score 1):

@dbush's answer is very good, just a quick add-on that hopefully may make things clear.  This is essentially what you're doing

```c
// In read-only memory. Just making these addresses up obviously.
// I don't know if they'd be more likely to be consecutively
// addressed or aligned in some way
0x100: "Hello World OLD"
0x200: "Hello World NEW"
```

Now in your loop

```c
// first iteration
pchar1 = "Hello World OLD";  // ==> now pchar1 == 0x100
pchar1 = "Hello World NEW";  // ==> now pchar1 == 0x200

// second iteration
pchar1 = "Hello World OLD";  // ==> now pchar1 == 0x100
pchar1 = "Hello World NEW";  // ==> now pchar1 == 0x200
```

and on forever, `pchar1` just keeps getting overwritten with the string literal address.

---

Addressing your new question in the comment (if I'm following):

It depends.  If you have an infinite loop that *allocates* memory each iteration (using `malloc`) or similar and you never `free` it, yes, you will have runaway memory consumption and eventually run out:

```c
#include <string.h>
...
// very simplified view
while(1)
{
   // alloctes 50 bytes
   pchar1 = malloc(50);
   // doesn't have to be a random string, "Hello World NEXT"
   // is still a string literal, lets say at address 0x300, but
   // each time you malloc it returns a _new_ pointer to _new_
   // memory. This new memory address is stored in pchar1. strcpy
   // _copies_ the string literal at address 0x300 into the new
   // memory pointed to by pchar1.
   strcpy(pchar1, "Hello World NEXT");
   // use pchar1
   // ...
   // WHOOPS, forgot to free. When you loop back around,
   // the previous value of pchar1 will be replaced with the
   // new value from malloc, but the previously allocated memory
   // will still be allocated. When you lose that previous pointer/
   // don't free it, that's called a memory leak. This loop will
   // allocate memory indefinitely until you run out.
}
```

In C, you have to manually manage your memory, which in general means you have to `free` every time you `malloc` ([but there's a debate about that depending on the situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36584062/should-i-free-memory-before-exit))

```c
// this is fine. Not best practice, but free of leaks
// and unbound memory allocation
while(1)
{
   pchar1 = malloc(50);
   // use pchar1 however
   free(pchar1);
}
```

Or, you can avoid dynamically allocating memory altogether:

```c
while(1)
{
   // here, pchar1 is allocated in _automatic storage_ (on the stack
   // in every C implementation I've ever used). Here, the program
   // "deallocates" pchar1 when the closing } is hit
   char pchar1[50];
   // the string literal is still at 0x300, we're just copying its
   // data into the pchar1 memory (different address than 0x300)
   strcpy(pchar1, "Hello World NEXT");
   // use pchar1
   // ...
   // ok, as soon as we hit this closing brace } pchar1 is
   // deallocated ... and reallocated new when we loop back
   // around
}
```

Comment: Thanks @yano, let's suppose that I generate a random string runtime whithin the loop, then I assign my pointer to that string, will that new string be allocated in another address?
If new address is used, then older one is preserved?

Comment: @EdherCarbajal tried to address you question with the edit, but not 100% sure I'm following

Comment: @EdherCarbajal: You have to allocate memory to store the string you're creating; you're just assigning the starting address of that memory to your pointer.  Whether that address changes or not and whether the address and contents of a previous string are preserved depends on how you allocate and deallocate the memory for the string.